# Group result set by weeks

Tags: mysql

I have a schema:

```
item | sales
1      10
1      20
1      30
2      10
2      20
2      30
```

How can I group the result so it's like:

```
item | total
1      60
2      60
```

I've tried

```
select sum(sales) as total, week from shop
where item = 1
order by total DESC
```

I'm not sure how to make it work without a lot of OR clauses

Answer (score 1):

You have to group by `item` in order to sum per item and not the complete data in the table

```
select sum(sales) as total, item
from shop
group by item
order by total DESC
```

Comment: Perfect, will accept answer after the 10 min limit :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a group by statement :

```
select item, sum(sales) as total
from shop
group by item
order by total desc
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select item, sum(sales) as total from shop 
GROUP BY item
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: I think you mean `GROUP BY item` rather than `GROUP BY shop`, don't you?